# Pillow Image.paste: Exporting image files with layers to Photoshop

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, photoshop

I am looking to automate image processing for an online store where a logo must be placed on various product images of clothing. Luckily, the newer product images are well aligned in most cases which eases the automation requirements of this task.

I have the following code that easily pastes the logo on these images based on predefined coordinates. However, I am still looking to eliminate errors where pictures of hoodies and jackets, for example, are aligned differently compared with t-shirts and polos. Any ideas on how I can retrieve the logo on top of the piece of clothing such that I could manually adjust any "errors" in Photoshop or similar? I am also open to other solutions that help achieve the desired outcomes.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

# Path to the folder containing product images
folder_path = "D:/..."
save_path = "D:/..."

# Path to the logo image
logo_path = "D:/.../x.png"
logo = Image.open(logo_path)
logo_width, logo_height = logo.size

# Iterate through each file in the folder
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    # if filename.endswith(".png"):  # Assuming all images are PNG, you can modify accordingly
        # Load the product image
        product_image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        product_image = Image.open(product_image_path)

        # Define where logo is placed on product image
        x, y = 618, 245
        region = (x, y, x + logo_width, y + logo_height)

        # Place logo on product image
        product_image.paste(logo, region, logo)

        # Save or display the modified image (choose one or both)
        # Save the modified image
        product_image.save(os.path.join(save_path, f"modified_{filename}"))

        # Display the modified image (optional)
        # product_image.show()
```

Comment: *"Retrieve"*? That means *"get"* - surely you are trying to position it, i.e. **put**, aren't you? Do you mean that you want to write a layered file such that you can load it into Photoshop and *"nudge"* the branding a little bit left/right, up/down? If so, maybe write a layered TIFF.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, Thanks for pointing out the error. Of course it's put. And yes, I want to be able to nudge the branding if necessary. I'll give the layered TIFF a try. Appreciate your help!